# Morrowind bug - all keywords have 's' prefixed

Tags: steam, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind, the-elder-scrolls-construction-set

Here's the problem: using Morrowind's Construction Set to change `Gameplay` > `Settings` > `fEncumbranceStrMult` to get more carry weight works like a charm, BUT there is a slight problem. Every text in-game a has an "S" in front of it (*sDexterity*, *sHealth*, *sLong Blade*, etc). 

How do I fix this?

Comment: Also just to be clear. I am not sure if the fEncumbranceStrMult change created the whole sproblem swith sthe ss sletter. On the Global > Menus tab there's Values and ID's and everything in there has an "S" in front of it.

Comment: Also just to add a minor information, when changing  fEncumbranceStrMult from the original value of 5.000 to 25.000 it ads a star infront of the  fEncumbranceStrMult ID (* fEncumbranceStrMult).

Comment: Are you saying that the *in-game menus* have the "s" in front of the stats? If it's only in the CK, then that's not a problem. Btw, the asterisk next to the value in the CK just means that it has been changed from the original, and needs to be saved.

Comment: Yes correct! The stats and skills, all item values and so on. I saved the change in CS and moved it in Morrowind > data and activated from the launcher. Removing it from the game also removes the S'ses obviously. Also thank you for replying!

Comment: When you go to *File > Data Files*, select your .ESP, and then click "Details", is the only change listed the encumbrance? Or does it show other changes? Also, I'm not entirely sure this question is on-topic for Arqade, now that I think of it...

Comment: It is the only change. And If this is not the right place to talk about this topic I can take this down? I vasically got ver the problem with a work around. I used the CS to modify my heavy armors weight a bit so I dont really need to get the fEncumbranceStrMult to work anymore. I thank you for the replies and the help! Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been encountered in Skyrim by someone [on the Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/535151589901044610/), too, although in this user's case it's a dollar sign '$' prefix instead of an 'S', and it wasn't caused by an edit. Since Skyrim and Morrowind use very similar editing tools, I suspect the problem has similar causes.

Here, **the problem was solved after validating the game files through Steam, and (inadvertently) changing the game's language.**

Apparently, the cause of this bug can be located either in the `.ini` files of the game, or the localized language files (which seems less likely).

I suggest backing up your `Morrowind.ini` (from 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Morrowind\`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\GOG Galaxy\Games\Morrowind\`, or `C:\Program Files\Bethesda Softworks\Morrowind\`), and removing it. Then, either by restarting the game, validating the files through Steam, or copying the file from your installation CD, reinstate the original default `.ini`.

If that doesn't fix the problem, changing the language might. First, change it to anything, then back to your preferred language. To change the language

- in Steam, right-click the game in your library, and select '*Preferences*'.
- using GOG, go to the game's page in GOG Galaxy, click on '*More*', then '*settings*'.
- if you have just the disc with the game files, it will be harder, so I suggest a complete reinstall.

---

As per your comment, the asterisk in front of the `fEncumbranceStrMult` string denotes an edit in the Morrowind Construction Set.